# In Django, how can I inherit a model that's not abstract as if it were abstract, so that I get a single table in the DB?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

Say I have a third party's model and it's not marked as abstract. I want to inherit it, add my own fields on top of that, and have it all be a single table in the database. Normally, that means I should inherit from an abstract model class, but I don't have that luxury in this case. Is there a way to have an intermediary step that creates an abstract class from the parent, so I can inherit from that one instead?

Comment: have you a third party app with migrations ? Can you guarantee (or you can ignore if )  such table will never change ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an intermediate abstract model and inherits from your third party model

```
    ThirdPartyModelClass(models.Model):
        #fields goes here

    AbstractThirdPartyModelClass(ThirdPartyModelClass):

       class Meta:
           abstract = True


    YourModel(AbstractThirdPartyModelClass,models.Model):
        #your fields
```

Comment: I had tried that. It creates the parent table and in the child table it creates a field that points to the parent table. The field name is <parent_table_name>_ptr_id.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can make a model with additional fields which will connect to the 'base' model by `OneToOne` relation. Using signals you can implement logic which will guarantee that every third-party model instance has 'extension' model instance created and connected.

I mean something like old recommended way to extend Django's `User` model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: This would created two tables in the database, though.

Comment: @Heliodor, right. If you really need it in one place — you can fork the third-party library and make any changes you need.

Comment: We used to use signals to create user extensions, but it was more troubles that advantages. So, I really discourage from using signals for this purpose.

Otherwise the additional model is fine, but makes two tables in database which is sometimes unwanted behaviour.